# Find Connection leak in Java application

Tags: java, oracle, connection-leaks

I have an application which starts giving me internal server error after some time, Some people I asked told me that this can be because of Connection leak in my application. I started searching and found this query to simulate connection leak.

`select LAST_CALL_ET, SQL_TEXT, username, machine, to_char(logon_time, 'ddMon hh24:mi') as login, SQL_HASH_VALUE, PREV_HASH_VALUE, status from v$session, v$sql where username='USERNAME' and HASH_VALUE =  PREV_HASH_VALUE
order by last_call_et desc;`.

I monitored my application with this query and closed all leaked connections for the query shown in this result. But now my application is starting to give same error for even less inactive sessions . 
Am I using the correct query to find out in active session / connection leak ? Someone told me condition HASH_VALUE =  PREV_HASH_VALUE in this query is wrong, But I do not know about these columns (not much DB knowledge.)

Thank you

Comment: Are you closing all of your `Statement`, `PreparedStatement`, `ResultSet`, and `Connection` objects?

Comment: @copeg Yes Sir, Currently I search all the queries that come into the result and I close everything . But sometimes i see same query in the inactive session result blocking some other queries even though connection and other objects are closed .

Comment: Is this a web application or stand-alone app? What connection pool library does it use?

Comment: @JeffMiller This is a web application. I am using tomcat JNDI and DBCP . 
I am closing every open connection found yet same query appears in the result and block other queries .

Comment: Sounds like you're closing your resources within the regular code block, but it needs to be done in a finally block so it happens even in the case of exceptions. That would explain why you're still leaking resources, but only occasionally.
Using try-with-resources will handle that for you automatically.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to find out leaks you can use profilers like [`yourkit`](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/builtin_probes.jsp) or [`jprofiler`](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) which is able to track socket/jdbc leaks.

To fix leaks you have to find out places where you opening connections and use try-with-resources which will do all `close()` stuff for you

```
try (Connection conection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
     PreparedStatement statement = createPreparedStatement(conection); 
     ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
     // process the resultSet here, all resources will be cleaned up
}
```

Comment: I am closing all the connection found, but still some query blocks others . 
I will try "try-with-resources" and see if this will resolve the issue .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most connection pools have a configuration to log connection leaks. I am not familiar with DBCP but the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) indicates that the **logAbandoned** property will log connection leaks. If you set logAbandoned to true, DCBP should log stack traces some time after the pool timeout property. The stack trace will contain the location where the leaked connection was opened.