# Java HTTP Response Body leaked... but never explicitly using a response body?

Tags: java, android, https, network-programming, httpresponse

I am working on an app in Android Studio that reads information from a REST API, parses it client-side, and then displays it. Everything is working and nothing crashes so far, but I keep getting the following log warning: 
`W/OkHttpClient: A connection to https://<site>.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?` I have a `cleanup()` function that closes my `InputStream` and `JsonReader`, and as you can see, I make sure to disconnect my HTTPS connection. This is the only place I use any type of networking logic. What else do I need to close?

```
 protected static JsonReader getAPI(String endpointURL) {
    JsonReader jsonReader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(endpointURL);
        // Create connection
        myConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            // Success
            // Further processing here
            InputStream inp = myConnection.getInputStream();
            try {
                jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inp, "UTF-8"));
                jsonReader.setLenient(true);
                //inp.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Serverside", inp.toString());
            }
        } else {
            // Error handling code goes here
            //hits here if no events! this is okay
            Log.i("Serverside", "URLConnection");
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        myConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return jsonReader;
}
```

EDIT: Here is a snippet of the logs:

```
03-31 06:59:16.758 15809-15809/com.rsenapp.triage I/Fix error: back pressed
03-31 06:59:16.785 15809-15924/com.rsenapp.triage V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 8279
03-31 06:59:16.785 15809-15924/com.rsenapp.triage V/FA: Connecting to remote service
03-31 06:59:16.798 1596-1609/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
03-31 06:59:16.799 1596-1609/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
03-31 06:59:16.811 15809-15924/com.rsenapp.triage V/FA: Activity paused, time: 15659169
03-31 06:59:16.822 15809-15924/com.rsenapp.triage D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=8279, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=EventviewActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-579304082464371239}]
03-31 06:59:16.870 15809-15924/com.rsenapp.triage V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
03-31 06:59:19.396 15809-15934/com.rsenapp.triage I/Serverside: URLConnection
03-31 06:59:19.402 15809-15934/com.rsenapp.triage I/System.out: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@34c53
03-31 06:59:20.579 15809-15934/com.rsenapp.triage I/Serverside: URLConnection
03-31 06:59:20.581 15809-15934/com.rsenapp.triage I/System.out: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@ddaf990
03-31 06:59:21.571 15809-15934/com.rsenapp.triage I/Serverside: URLConnection
03-31 06:59:21.573 15809-15934/com.rsenapp.triage I/System.out: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@3a65289
03-31 06:59:21.792 1390-1528/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 6962632 , only wrote 6714000
03-31 06:59:23.019 15809-15884/com.rsenapp.triage W/OkHttpClient: A connection to https://rsenapp.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
03-31 06:59:23.020 15809-15884/com.rsenapp.triage I/chatty: uid=10082(com.rsenapp.triage) OkHttp Connecti identical 9 lines
03-31 06:59:23.020 15809-15884/com.rsenapp.triage W/OkHttpClient: A connection to https://rsenapp.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
03-31 06:59:23.589 1596-1658/? I/InputDispatcher: Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{c65626d token=Token{8968a84 ActivityRecord{2677897 u0 com.rsenapp.triage/.MainActivity t49}}}.  It has been 5006.8ms since event, 5003.5ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.
03-31 06:59:23.590 1596-1658/? I/WindowManager: Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{c65626d token=Token{8968a84 ActivityRecord{2677897 u0 com.rsenapp.triage/.MainActivity t49}}}.  Reason: Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.
03-31 06:59:23.620 1596-1658/? W/InputDispatcher: Asynchronous input event injection timed out.
03-31 06:59:23.724 15809-15809/com.rsenapp.triage I/Serverside: [com.rsenapp.triage.Event@9ed128e, com.rsenapp.triage.Event@d6c5aaf, com.rsenapp.triage.Event@d1e1ebc, com.rsenapp.triage.Event@4988e45, com.rsenapp.triage.Event@eabc99a, com.rsenapp.triage.Event@dadf2cb, com.rsenapp.triage.Event@70c6aa8, com.rsenapp.triage.Event@eb8c9c1, com.rsenapp.triage.Event@e6ce566, com.rsenapp.triage.Event@526f0a7, com.rsenapp.triage.Event@7118954]
03-31 06:59:23.724 15809-15809/com.rsenapp.triage I/EventList: Current Event: rtCatpcha: Video, voice, and smarts for secure authentication
03-31 06:59:23.724 15809-15809/com.rsenapp.triage I/EventList: Current Event: Distributed Algorithms for Pattern Matching in Massive Labelled Graphs
03-31 06:59:23.724 15809-15809/com.rsenapp.triage I/EventList: Current Event: Privacy, Security, Internet, and the Coming Clash of Cultures
03-31 06:59:23.724 15809-15809/com.rsenapp.triage I/EventList: Current Event: Joshua Sorenson: Solving the Biggest Problems 
03-31 06:59:23.724 15809-15809/com.rsenapp.triage I/EventList: Current Event: More Data, More Science and… Moore’s Law?
```

Note that the stack traces that occur around the warning message are expected -- they are getting printed because, as we loop through all of the API routes, we sometimes reach lists that do not yet have information to share (e.g. a group that has no current events). Also, for right now, the data is pulled completely fresh with each change of screen -- we do not store the pulled data to pass between screens. The warning appears pretty consistently whenever a screen with API-pulled data is displayed.

ANOTHER EDIT: Here are the class fields and how they are closed via a cleanup method:

```
public class JSONParser {

    private static HttpsURLConnection myConnection;
    private static InputStream inp;
    private static JsonReader jsonReader;

    private static void cleanup() {
        if (inp != null) {
            try {
                inp.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (jsonReader != null) {
            try {
                jsonReader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this answer could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39474477/3694269

Comment: can you post more log related to the warning ? Need to read the log to see whats wrong.

Comment: @Ash I tried updating it with as much relevant information as I could -- the logs are very messy, but I tried to isolate them to where the warning message occurred.

Comment: OK. tell me one simple thing bro. Are you Using OKHttp in your project ?

Comment: @Ash Literally no. Not directly, at least. All I seem to be using is `HttpsURLConnection.`Like I said, what I have posted is the only networking code on the client side. Could it possibly be a problem with the back-end database/server side? The two sides are pretty distinct and are worked on by entirely separate groups of people.

Comment: @jiccan how did you solve this?